# Вёрстка label для загрузки файлов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При клике на данный объект должно открываться окно загрузки файла.
Следовательно, это должен быть label. Проблема в том, что у него есть тень вокруг и внутренний отступ от неё(эффект жирной рамки). При наведении должно затемняться изображение внутри. Как это можно сделать?
Пробовал через img внутри и ::after с тёмным фоном для него, но не помогло. Можно с примерном на codepen?

Comment: выложите Вашу разметку html и то, что пробовали.

Comment: https://codepen.io/pen/rNaRryy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К тегу `<img>` добавление псевдоэлементов неприменимо. Поэтому, добавляем `:after` к `<label>`.

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: box-shadow .4s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
label:hover::after { box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label for="fi">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Tom_Hardy_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg" alt="">
</label>

<input type="file" id="fi" hidden>
```